# Creating a non-atomic measure from atoms

Tags: measure-theory

Given a value measure $V$ defined on a "cake" (an interval), we would like to divide the cake to two disjoint "piece" (sub-intervals) with equal value.

If $V$  is non-atomic, e.g. when there is a finite continuous density function $v$ on the interval, and $V(A)$ is defined as the integral of $v$ over $A$, then an equal division always exists.

But if $V$ is atomic, e.g. when there is a set P of "value points", and $V(A)$ is defined as the number of points in $P\cap A$, then an equal division not always exists. In particular, if the number of value points is odd, then in any division, the number of value points in each piece will be different by at least 1.

So far - all is clear.

But now, what if we do not require the pieces to be disjoint, but rather allow them to overlap in a single point? In this case, it seems that an equal division always exists in the second case, too. So, this small compromise allows us to treat the atomic measure as a non-atomic measure in that it can be divided continuously.

My question is: is there a more formal and general way to define a non-atomic value measure, based on a set of value points?